# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "..." at path "_id"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have an issue with MongoDB `_id` value in Mongoose.

I have a url that uses `_id`, it looks like this: `/posts/53b42b3d2cc1ef603b41d54a`.

The problem is that when I obtain this `id` from `request.params`, Mongoose throws an error:

```
ERROR:  { [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "3b42b3d2cc1ef603b41d54a" at path "_id"]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "3b42b3d2cc1ef603b41d54a" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: '3b42b3d2cc1ef603b41d54a',
  path: '_id' }
```

But when I explicitly hard-code the `_id`, no errors are thrown and I get the data from a database just fine.

Here my code:

```
// This works fine, no errors are thrown
var _id = new mongoose.Schema.ObjectId("53b42b3d2cc1ef603b41d54a").path;

// This throws an error.
// But req.params[0] is just the same value:
// /post/53b42b3d2cc1ef603b41d54a
var _id = new mongoose.Schema.ObjectId(req.params[0]).path;

Post.findById(_id, function (err, posts) {

    if (err) {
        console.log("ERROR: ", err);
    }

    var model = {
        posts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts))
    };

    console.log("model: ", model);

    res.render('posts', model);
});
```

Why it happens? What is wrong here? How to cast the `req.params[0]` right way?

**UPD**:

`req.params` throws the leading `5` away from my url.

Here is a url:

`posts/53b42b3d2cc1ef603b41d54a`

And here is what `req.params` returns:

`{ '0': '3b42b3d2cc1ef603b41d54a' }`

Why it happens?

**UPD 2**

It was because of wrong regExp for the route.

The wrong one that cut off the first character: `/^\/[^new](\w+)$/`

The correct one: `/^\/([^new]\w+)$/`

And the full code now:

```
router.get(/^\/([^new]\w+)$/, function(req, res) {
    var _id = new mongoose.Schema.ObjectId(req.params[0]).path;

    Posts.findById(_id, function (err, posts) {

            if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR: ", err);
            }

            var model = {
                posts: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts))
            };

            res.render('posts', model);
    });    
});
```

Comment: `3b42b3d2cc1ef603b41d54a` is not a valid ObjectId. It has only 23 characters.

Comment: Looks like you somehow stripped the leading character somewhere.

Comment: @GergoErdosi, yes, you are right. I see it now. But it is not me, `req.params[0]` returns `{ '0': '3b42b3d2cc1ef603b41d54a' }`. For some reason the leading `5` is thrown away. How can it be? The url is `/posts/53b42b3d2cc1ef603b41d54a`, but the leading `5` is thrown away.

Comment: This code looks good, it is removed somewhere else. It is hard to tell where exactly without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: @GergoErdosi, I found an issue. It was about my regExp for the route, it cut the first character. The correct one: `/^\/([^new]\w+)$/`. The wrong one was: `/^\/[^new](\w+)$/`